# Show $\operatorname{p.\!v.}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,$ is an odd distribution

Tags: distribution-theory, cauchy-principal-value

Let  $\varphi$ be a test function (belonging to the set of smooth functions with compact support) We define the distribution principal value of $1/x$:

$$\left\langle\operatorname{p.\!v.}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),\varphi\right\rangle: =\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x\right]$$

How do I show it is an odd distribution?

An odd distribution $T$, is such that  $T(-t)=-T(t)$

My try:

\begin{align}\left\langle\operatorname{p.\!v.}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),\varphi\right\rangle&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon} \frac{\varphi(-x)}{-x} \, \mathrm{d}(-x) + \int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty} \frac{\varphi(-x)}{-x} \, \mathrm{d}(-x)\right]\\\left\langle\operatorname{p.\!v.}\left(\frac{1}{-x}\right),\varphi\right\rangle&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon} \frac{\varphi(-x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}(x) + \int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty} \frac{\varphi(-x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}(x)\right]\end{align}

But I don't know what to do with the $\varphi(-x)$, since it is an arbitrary test function, I can't say of it is odd or even. Besides I am not sure if it is ok to do $\left\langle\operatorname{p.\!v.}\left(\frac{1}{-x}\right),\varphi\right\rangle$ in the first place, because of the angular brackets.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}\left\langle\operatorname{p.\!v.}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),\varphi\right\rangle&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x}\,dx+ \int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x}\,dx\right]\\&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty} \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(-x)}{x}\,dx\\\left\langle\operatorname{p.\!v.}\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right),\varphi\right\rangle&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty} \frac{\varphi(-x)-\varphi(x)}{-x}\,d(-x)\\&=-\left\langle\operatorname{p.\!v.}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),\varphi\right\rangle\end{align}

Comment: I perform the substitution $u=-x$ in $\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon}\varphi(x)/x\,dx$, thus giving $\int_\infty^\varepsilon\varphi(-u)/(-u)\,d(-u)=\int_\varepsilon^\infty\varphi(u)/u\,du$ and then replaced $u$ back to $x$. For further details see [Wikipedia: Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Distribution_theory).

Comment: The last integral of your comment should  have inside the integral $\varphi(-u)/u$ and the previous one has the limits swapped

Comment: That was a typo, but you get the idea hopefully.

Comment: I do, thank you